# Module not found error in the github action workflow

Tags: python, flask, continuous-integration, github-actions

I created functional tests for the flask app. When i type `pytest` on my local environments all test are worked and are passed. When I try to start tests with github workflow, the same tests fail. One of the module from quizproject can't be found.I have no idea why this is happening. I tried debugging it but had no results.
CI failing due to following error:

```
Run pytest
ImportError while loading conftest '/home/runner/work/quiz-roads/quiz-roads/tests/conftest.py'.
tests/conftest.py:10: in <module>
    from quizproject.models.users import User as NewUser
E   ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'quizproject.models.users'
Error: Process completed with exit code 4.
```

my project structure"

```
quiz-roads/
|-- requirements.txt
|-- run.py
|-- quizproject/
|   |-- forms/
|   |   |-- form.py
|   |   |-- __init__.py
|   |-- models/
|   |   |-- users.py
|   |   |-- __init__.py
|   |-- templates/
|   |-- static/
|   |-- __init__.py
|   |-- auth.py
|   |-- main.py
|-- tests/
|   |-- functional/
|   |   |-- __init__.py
|   |   |-- test_auth.py
|   |   |-- test_users.py
|   |-- __init__.py
|   |-- confest.py
```

```
name: 'coverage'
on:
    pull_request:
        branches:
            - master
            - main
jobs:
    coverage:
        runs-on: ubuntu-latest
        strategy:
            fail-fast: false
        steps:
          - uses: actions/checkout@v3
          - name: Set up Python 3.10.6
            uses: actions/setup-python@v3
            with:
              python-version: 3.10.6
          - name: Install dependencies
            run: |
              cd $GITHUB_WORKSPACE
              python -m pip install --upgrade pip
              python -m pip install genbadge[all] pytest coverage
              # if [ -f requirements.txt ]; then pip install -r requirements.txt; fi
              pip install -r requirements.txt
          - name: show python path
            run: |
              python -c "import sys; print('\n'.join(sys.path))"
          - name: Generate report with coverage in the console
            run: |
              pytest
              coverage run -m pytest
              coverage report -m
```

class with the following error - confest.py

```
import datetime

import pytest
from sqlalchemy import delete


# import the module
from quizproject import create_app
from quizproject import db as _db
from quizproject.models.users import User as NewUser 
from config import TestingConfig
from werkzeug.security import generate_password_hash


...
```

my class that need to be loaded

```
import datetime
from importlib.metadata import MetadataPathFinder
from flask_login import UserMixin
from .. import db


metadata = MetadataPathFinder()


class User(UserMixin, db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "users",
    metadata,
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    register_time = db.Column(
        db.DateTime, default=datetime.datetime.utcnow(), nullable=False)
    last_login = db.Column(
        db.DateTime, default=datetime.datetime.utcnow(), nullable=False)
    user_email = db.Column(db.String(100), unique=True, nullable=False)
    user_password = db.Column(db.String(100), nullable=False)
    user_name = db.Column(db.String(1000), unique=True, nullable=False)

    def get_id(self):
        return (self.user_id)
```

full ci code can be found [here](https://github.com/DarekRepos/quiz-roads/blob/master/.github/workflows/workflow.yml)

I tried to move the `tests` folder to the `quizproject` folder, but got the same error.

Comment: I don't see you doing anything wrong. You have the same project structure (I wouldn't put *tests/* under *quizproject/* - that's really not necessary) and similar approach to testing as many projects of mine where it works. What output do you get for `python -c "import sys; print('\n'.join(sys.path))"` that you included in your workflow?

Comment: i got 
```Run python -c "import sys; print('\n'.join(sys.path))"
  python -c "import sys; print('\n'.join(sys.path))"
  shell: /usr/bin/bash -e {0}
  env:
    pythonLocation: /opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.10.6/x64
    LD_LIBRARY_PATH: /opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.10.6/x64/lib

/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.10.6/x64/lib/python310.zip
/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.10.6/x64/lib/python3.10
/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.10.6/x64/lib/python3.10/lib-dynload
/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.10.6/x64/lib/python3.10/site-packages```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After hours of debug this issue, I found the cause of the problem. It was simple...

I changed the module name from uppercase (`Users.py`) to lowercase (`users.py`). Git did not get changes. I had different letter on the remote repository and different letter of the file on my local repo. therefore "github action" failed and everything works on local enviroments.

I also went to git documentation and played with `core.ignoreCase` Internal variable. This enables various workarounds to enable Git to work better on filesystems that are not case sensitive, like  FAT, NTFS, etc.

i changed this settings temporary only for this one repo by command.

`git config core.ignorecase false`

the file color for user.py change to green ( by default new file in my local repository).

i removed and added file again to the repository (users.py).
i committed the file (users.py). I had to delete from remote repository file with upper case (Users.py).

It resolved this issue.

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer. I got same issue and it took me hours to find out :]